# Model comparison for predictors with differently shaped distributions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, predictor, model-comparison

I want to use model comparison to evaluate the claim "Predictor A outperforms Predictor B in modeling Dependent X". The (potential) problem is that within my sample, Predictor A and Predictor B have distributions with somewhat different shapes (see below); this is because the sample was systematically chosen to represent a certain range of Predictor A values, but not Predictor B (assume that for both predictors, the sample distribution adequately represents the population distribution). Given the different scales, assume that the predictors will be standardized.
[image]

Given the differences in distribution shapes, does it make sense to compare a model with Predictor A vs. a model with Predictor B (where nothing else differs between the models)? Or would any claim about one model being a better fit than the other be undermined by the different distribution shapes? (If it matters, the response is binary, modeled via lme4::glmer in R, and model fit is assessed via log-likelihood.)

Comment: How do you want to model this? With regression? If so, the distribution of the IV's are not relevant.

Comment: You might consider "dependent X = f(A, B)" to make a 3D surface fit. If you can post a link to the data, I can perform a surface fitting equation search and see what it turns up regarding candidate equations.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy1ypv3w3cde658/dat.csv?dl=0